# swift 2.2 new syntax for loops

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

i have to modify my for loops of my swift 2 app.
at the moment i use this syntax

```
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
```

i learned that i have to use this:

```
for x in 0..<5 {
```

but how i have to change this for loop:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 6; x = x+2) {
```

Comment: Generally – as advised in your former question – **do not** use parentheses around `if / for / while` etc. conditions in Swift

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `stride` function

```
 // for x<6
 for i in 0.stride(to: 6, by: 2) {
    print(i)   // 0,2,4
 }

 //for x<=6
 for i in 0.stride(through: 6, by: 2) {
    print(i)  // 0,2,4,6
 }
```

Comment: @El Caption strikes here also :)

Answer (score 1):

In Easy way Try this,

```
var x = 0
for x in 0..<5 {
    x += 2
}
print(x)
```

check this link for more reference [Swift 2.2 tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html)